# Total beginner question: execute two functions

Tags: javascript, function

I am just begging to understand JS and have a simple question that I hope, someone will be able to answer. I am working in google tag manager and I need the script to fill the bunch of hidden form fields. The values for the form fields are delivered via several google tag manager variables {{my var.1,2,3, etc.}.  I created a single function that works fine for one variable

```
 <script>
(function(){
var selector = $('[id="input_11_49"],   [id="input_15_14"], [id="input_17_14"], [id="input_18_14"], [id="input_19_14"], [id="input_2_71"],  [id="input_20_14"], [id="input_21_14"], [id="input_3_36"],  [id="input_6_62"]') 

$(selector).val('{{my_GTM_variable1}}')
})();

</script>
```

Now I am looking to perform another function (5 in total) and looking for the right way to do this. Tested this approach but it's not working. I know there is a bunch of syntax errors.

```
<script>
(function 1 (){
var selector = $('[id="input_11_49"],   [id="input_15_14"], [id="input_17_14"], [id="input_18_14"], [id="input_19_14"], [id="input_2_71"],  [id="input_20_14"], [id="input_21_14"], [id="input_3_36"],  [id="input_6_62"]')

$(selector).val('{{my_GTM_variable1}}')}
  
 (function 2 (){
var selector = $('[id="input_11_50"],   [id="input_15_15"], [id="input_17_15"], [id="input_18_15"], [id="input_19_15"], [id="input_2_75"],  [id="input_20_15"], [id="input_21_15"], [id="input_3_37"],  [id="input_6_63"]') 

$(selector).val('{{my_GTM_variable2}}')
})();

</script>
```

Hope someone can give me input. Thank you in advance!

Comment: those are called IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression - i dont think you can call them directly unless you give them a valid name.

Comment: @user3191724 Rather adding selectors as CSV, use find by attribute 
           Your hidden field :  **<hidden data-gtm="1" id="yourids"></hidden>**
**$("hidden[data-gtm*='1']").val({{my_GTM_variable1}});**

Comment: @DanielA.White Those function can be called directly, i dont know what he is trying to do but functions without name can be invoked under script tag

Comment: `function 1` `function 2` will both throw syntax errors, just use `function` for both

Answer (score 1):

A pure JAvascript example will look like follow. the variable {{your var in tag manager}} is doesnt metter how you named it

```
(function() {
    selector1 = ['#a', '#b', '#c'];
    val1 = [
      {{var1}}
    ];
    selector2 = ['#d', '#e', '#f'];
    val2 = [
      {{var2}}
    ]
    slectorenlen = 2;
    for (i = 1; i <= slectorenlen; i++) {
        len = eval("selector" + i + ".length");
        for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
            eval("document.querySelector(selector" + i + "[n]).value=val" + i);
        }
    }
})()
```